Tips for improving the look of projectiles in Unity
Is there some better way of instantiating simple projectiles in Unity so that they look better (esp while moving). Currently, it looks like this for me (blue marks player's move direction, yellow marks direction I'm firing in).

My fire rate and the bullet's speed is set quite high, but as best as I can tell, I believe there's some delay from when the bullet is created, before it actually accelerates to the intended speed? Just a few frames, but more than enough to make it look weird.
With more bullets etc, naturally it looks even stranger.
Here is the code I use to fire these bullets:
public class RangedWeapon : Weapon
{
    [Header("General")]
    [SerializeField] protected Transform firePoint;
    [SerializeField] protected Projectile projectile;

    protected override void HandleFire()
    {
        Projectile proj = Instantiate(projectile, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        proj.Fire(firePoint.forward);
    }
}

public class Projectile : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] protected float speed;
    [SerializeField] protected float lifeTime;
    protected Rigidbody rbody;
    protected float timer;

    protected void Awake()
    {
        rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public void Fire(Vector3 dir)
    {
        transform.forward = dir;
        rbody.velocity = transform.forward * speed;
    }
}

A debug of the speed of the projectile's speed after a single shot shows the following via the code
    protected void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log($"CurrentSpeed: {rbody.velocity.magnitude}");
        if (timer >= lifeTime)
        {
            DestroyProjectile();
        }
    }


So as you can see, there is a single Update call where the speed is 0 (presumably when the object is first created). What I need is to be able to "prewarm" the object or something.

Could you check if the projectile speed really has a delay before reaching the intended speed by displaying the log? put Debug.Log(rbody.velocity); in Projectile.cs Update function?

from that image it is hard to tell what the issue is ... what exactly would you expect vs what exactly happens instead? I can only guess and you don't like how the bullets are moving to the right while you are moving forward ... but if you fire in that direction I'd say that is actually quite accurate .. except that in the real world you would probably also adapt some portion of the forward movement, even if just a tiny percentage

@mejan I've updated the post with the debug logs, and you can definitely see the single frame of 0 speed.

@derHugo I have tried a few things including that, but with these debug logs I've added, I think the issue is more obvious, which is the delay before the speed actually applies.

I see a delay of one single frame ... that is basically impossible to see

Because I can't add videos, it is very hard to describe the actual effect. Though the debug only SHOWS 1 frame, the actual delay is longer.
The most obvious tell of this happening is in the picture in the post, where, if the player is moving forwards, then you would naturally expect the previous bullet to be a little bit more (towards the right) than the one just fired.
When this is not the case, it is super obvious visually.

You're probably firing those bullets on Update, which is correct, but keep in mind physics is on FixedUpdate so maybe your velocity assignment doesn't take effect until the next physics tick. You can try manually moving the bullets via transform on Update, even just to quickly see if it actually solves whatever looks wrong to you and not as a permanent solution.

put the video on other site (i.e. youtube) and share the link here. is the projectile collider's isTrigger is set to true?

I'll see about posting a video later, but @Verpous using transform.Translate instead of adding force to rigidbody makes it look perfect and exactly as expected . . . though obviously this isn't a final solution, but I guess that means that the force IS delayed?
Any ideas?
mejan I'll see about doing a vid or something, but I haven't set up anything to do stuff like that before so itll take a bit. Why does the isTrigger matter?

Just tossing ideas: you can try 1) increasing the physics tick rate, 2) setting the bullets interpolation mode to "extrapolate", 3) remembering on Update that you need to fire a bullet but only firing it on FixedUpdate

Perhaps you need to "compensate" for the time delta between the Update and FixedUpdate by instantiating the bullet a little bit ahead according to where it would be if it was already moving for that delta.

@Verpous if you like, please respond with your point 3) so I can mark it as the answer - it completely fixed my issue
Thanks all for the help!

The problem is because you fire the bullet on Update but velocity only kicks in once Unity reaches the nearest by FixedUpdate. You can fix this by remembering on Update that you need to fire a bullet, but only actually firing it on FixedUpdate.
